# "Local Network Share" Option Missing

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing, shared-folders

I'm new to Ubuntu and just installed 23.04 on a new rig. I am trying to set up local network file sharing between my Ubuntu machine and my Windows laptop such that I can save/move/delete files in the shared folder on the Ubuntu computer from my Windows laptop.

In following guides, I installed Samba and allowed it access to the network. However, when I right-click on the folder I want to designate as the shared folder, the drop-down menu is missing "Local Network Share". Is there a setting or package I missed?

Comment: are you in group `sambashare` (logout/login after adding to group) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing a package. See if you can install it:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-share
```

Then it will be listed as "Sharing Options"